# how to interact with shadow DOM elements for take the file.pdf with selenium 4.x, using php and chrome driver V95.0.?

Tags: javascript, php, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

Explain better:
I am automating the issuance of a certificate that is being generated in iframes

Through the selenium grid I managed to get to this last screen where the pdf is
[image: selenium_grid]
I tried to print the screen with window.print running a javascript, I see the window for print but I couldn't proceed
:

```
$this->driver->executeScript("window.print()");






document.querySelector('pdf-viewer').shadowRoot.querySelector('viewer-toolbar').shadowRoot.querySelector('viewer-download-controls').shadowRoot.querySelector('cr-icon-button').click();//this work in browser, nope with selenium
```

From where I am I think there could be some ways to solve which I tried but didn't make any progress:

- after `windows.print()` ,
- - press o key enter, maybe(two times),
- - click button save
- maybe using keyboard `control + s` , `key enter`
- right click, save page as, confirm
- maybe using `control + p`
- maybe using mouse for click in arrow down for download, but I got not find element, or dont know how to use coordinates for mouse
- set preferences/capabilities for browser for when the window.print() not show where I liked save my pdf
  I too tried set a preferences
  I too tried `$this->driver->getPageSource();`

  $options->addArguments(['--print-to-pdf']);

that I find [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) but not sure if it is working or how to use it.

```html
<iframe src="asintegrarelatorio?UGsAuJNIMg0Bs79efCz_UN+WLY3wJLa3shybBaN2MhtwcBuQ28HYLHZjlWoShKh3akHt0HZM3+pL7TP3ksZMQQ==" name="EMBPAGE" width="900px" height="500px" frameborder="1" align="center" title="" style="" scrolling="auto">
<html><head><script src="chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/prompt.js"></script></head><body style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin:0px; background-color: rgb(82, 86, 89);"><embed name="C065A881B0E7E51799DF65DCF351573F" style="position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" width="100%" height="100%" src="about:blank" type="application/pdf" internalid="C065A881B0E7E51799DF65DCF351573F"></body></html>


</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("#printDiv > a").setAttribute("onclick","setTimeout(() => window.print(), 0);")')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).